# Bootstrap datepicker's position issue inside bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Here is the code for date-picker:

```
<div id="divDOBPicker">
    <label id="lbldate">Date of birth </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="date-control" placeholder="Select Date" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="s-plus"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have placed the above code inside the body of bootstrap modal popup. In fullscreen view, the date-picker behaves as expected.

But in small screens, when windows-scroll-bar comes into picture, the datepicker gets separated from the input control. As in the datepicker doesn't move when user scrolls up/down.

Comment: have you added any custom css?

Comment: Yes Ozan.. but the CSS are to override the color only. I am not over-riding the position.